# Angular Dropdown Selected Item not picking up right value

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

Here is my dropdown

```
 <select class="form-control" data-ng-options="obj.text for obj in options track by obj.value" data-ng-model="submission.issue" ng-init="submission.issue = options[0]" required></select>
```

This is populating my dropdown ok but when I view the value of "submission.issue" I don't see the value of the option items in the select as expected but rather something like

```
"Query {"text":"Select your query","value":""} "
```

Where by Default I just want submission.issue default item to be first one in the list which has a value of "".

Here is how I populate the list

```
$scope.options = [
          { text: $scope.select_default, value: "" },
          { text: $scope.select_issue_1, value: $scope.select_issue_1 },
          { text: $scope.select_issue_2, value: $scope.select_issue_2 },
          { text: $scope.select_issue_3, value: $scope.select_issue_3 },
          { text: $scope.select_issue_4, value: $scope.select_issue_4 },
          { text: $scope.select_issue_5, value: $scope.select_issue_5 }
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ng-options expression to read as follows:

```
"obj.value as obj.text for obj in options track by obj.value"
```

$scope.submission.issue should equal the value of the selected item in your dropdown.